# Changing color of a row of listview according to item

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, colors, row

I want to change the color of my Listview according to its status.
I have two status, the "PENDING" that I want to change in Red Color and "COMPLETE" to Blue.
How is it possible? I have no Idea since this is my first time to do it in a list view.

Comment: what that means is that you should have a column in the database named status with data P for pending and C for complete

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps:

```
Dim ListView1 As ListView = New ListView
    ListView1.BackColor = if(status.tolower = "pending",Color.Red, Color.Blue)
```

Or you can colour indiviual items:

```
Dim lvi As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem
    lvi.Text = "Test"
    lvi.BackColor = if(status.tolower = "pending",Color.Red, Color.Blue)
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you never use `IIf`.  It's a garbge VB function.  Use a conditional `If` instead.

Comment: You can still do it like this: `_backColor = If(status.tolower = "pending", Color.Red,  Color.Blue)`.  My point was that `IIf` is an awful function that evaluates both parts of the condition regardless of how the (boolean) first parameter evaluates.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I've updated again...it's easier to read inline

Comment: I happen to agree, although not everyone will.

Comment: I got error in `If(status.tolower` how can i ifx that. And where can I put that code? In the Form_load?

Comment: You'll have to replace status with whatever object that has the status in it.

Comment: I dont have Idea. My Status is in the 5th column. How can I code that? Is `ListView1.Items(4).Text` correct?

Comment: Yes, try it and run in debug to see what the value is (don't forget the .ToLower() part. You should put `ListView1.Items(4).Text.ToLower`

Comment: I got an error: **InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index**

Comment: Please help me. I need it badly. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
                    With ListView1.Items(i)
                        .UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
                        If .Items(i).SubItems.Count > 1 Then
                            .Items(i).SubItems(0).ForeColoe = Color.Green
                            .Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.Yellow
                            .Items(i).SubItems(2).BackColor = Color.Red
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
```

Comment: Have you ever tried your own code? There is no `.ForeColoe`  only  `.ForeColor` . And you can't use `.items(i).SubItems...` again within your with... command.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub changeselectedItemcolour()
    Try
        'Get currently selected items index value

        Dim i = ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).Index
        Dim k As Integer = 0

        'loop entire list and reset colors
        While k <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            ListView1.Items(k).BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
            ListView1.Items(k).ForeColor = Color.Black
            k = k + 1
        End While

        'set the selected items color
        Try
            ListView1.Items(i).BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight
            ListView1.Items(i).ForeColor = Color.Red
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i did mine i added these codes to my listview loop event

ListView1.Items.Clear()

```
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim recordinsert As SqlCommand
    Dim searchme As SqlDataReader
    Dim strQuery As String
    conn = New SqlConnection(dbClass.Globconn)
    conn.Open()
        strQuery = "select * from salesdetail where invno= '" & txtProformaNo.Text & "' order by snno"

    recordinsert = New SqlCommand(strQuery, conn)
    searchme = recordinsert.ExecuteReader
    Do While searchme.Read()
        Lv = ListView1.Items.Add(searchme("snno"))

            Lv.SubItems.Add(searchme("stkcode"))
            Lv.SubItems.Add(searchme("stkdes"))
            Lv.SubItems.Add(searchme("qty"))
            Lv.SubItems.Add(searchme("sprice"))
            Lv.SubItems.Add(searchme("amt"))
        If searchme("status") = "S" Then
            Lv.ForeColor = Color.Green
        Else
            Lv.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

i put in my database a type numbers so wherever the subitems 7 gives a number the column color will change according to what is saved in the database

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
            ListView1.Items(i).UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
            If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems.Count > 1 Then
                ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite

                If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(5).Text > 0 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(5).BackColor = Color.Red
                End If

                If ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text = 0 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White

                ElseIf ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text = 1 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.LightGray
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White

                ElseIf ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text = 2 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White

                ElseIf ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text = 3 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White
                ElseIf ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text = 4 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite
                ElseIf ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text = 5 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.LightGreen
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White
                ElseIf ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text = 6 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.CadetBlue
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.White
                ElseIf ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(7).Text = 7 Then
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).BackColor = Color.LightYellow
                    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(1).ForeColor = Color.Black
                End If
            End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

UseItemStyleForSubItems  is very important to set FALSE

```
It = New ListViewItem
It.UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
t.SubItems(It.SubItems.Count - 1).BackColor = Color.Red
```