# Change Colour of Individual Item In Listview in Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a **ListView** instead of a listbox, to give me some control over the background colours for individual rows.

I have achieved changing the listview background colour as a whole for example: BackColor = &HC000& - However, I want to make one of the rows its own colour.

```
With ListView1
   .View = lvwReport
   .CheckBoxes = True
   .FullRowSelect = True
   .Gridlines = True
   .BackColor = &HC000&
   With .ColumnHeaders
      .Clear
      .Add , , "Language", 70
      .Add , , "Subitem-1", 70
      .Add , , "Subitem-2", 70
   End With


   Dim li As ListItem

   Set li = .ListItems.Add()

   li.Bold = True 'Bold item

   'li.BackColor = Color.Gold
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Subitem 1.1"
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Subitem 1.2"


   Set li = .ListItems.Add()
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Subitem 2.1"
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Subitem 2.2"

   Set li = .ListItems.Add()

   li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Subitem 3.1"
   li.ListSubItems.Add , , "Subitem 3.2"


   .ColumnHeaders(1).Position = 2
End With
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300248/changing-color-of-a-row-of-listview-according-to-item) for example? Would that be helpfull?

Comment: Do you want the (complete) row (back)color or the fontcolor in that row?

Comment: complete row, and back colour

Comment: I think it's not possible in VBA (ForeColor is) [Maybe a picture with colored rows as background?]

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense then